# SQL SELECT JOIN COLUMN ALIAS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks in advance for your help:

`[People]` table has two columns:

- PersonID
- PersonName

`[Marriages]` table has three columns:

- MarriageID
- PersonIDa
- PersonIDb

I want to SELECT the following columns:

- MarriageID
- PersonName (for personIDa)
- PersonName (for personIDb)

I think I need to use a `SELECT` statement with a `JOIN`, but I'm not sure how to assign a unique alias to each `PersonName`. This is what I have so far (that doesn't work):

```
SELECT 
    [Marriages].[MarriageID], 
    [People].[PersonName] AS aName, 
    [People].[PersonName] AS bName  
FROM 
    [Marriages]  
JOIN 
    [People] ON [Marriages].[PersonIDa] = [People].[PersonID]  
JOIN 
    [People] ON [Marriages].[PersonIDb] = [People].[PersonID]
```

Thanks again...

Comment: You will not need square brackets around table and column names as long as you do not use SQL keywords or non-western characters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this match what you're trying to accomplish?

```
SELECT m.[MarriageID], peopleA.[PersonName] AS aName, peopleB.[PersonName] AS bName  
FROM [Marriages]  M
JOIN [People] peopleA ON m.[PersonIDa] = peopleA.[PersonID]  
JOIN [People] peopleB ON m.[PersonIDb] = peopleB.[PersonID]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to do this...

```
SELECT 
m.[MarriageID], 
pa.[PersonName] AS aName,
pb.[PersonName] AS bName  
FROM [Marriages] m
JOIN [People] pa ON m.[PersonIDa] = pa.[PersonID]  
JOIN [People] pb ON m.[PersonIDb] = pb.[PersonID];
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need something like:

```
Select MarriageID, a.PersonName, b.PersonName
From Marriages m
Join People a On a.PersonID = m.Person1ID 
Join People b on b.PersonID = m.Person2ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget what type of JOIN you need..."INNER JOIN" / "LEFT OUTER JOIN" / "RIGHT OUTER JOIN"/ "CROSS JOIN"

```
SELECT MarriageID, a.PersonName, b.PersonName
FROM Marriages m JOIN People a ON a.PersonID = m.Person1ID 
                 JOIN People b ON b.PersonID = m.Person2ID
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone; your suggestions worked perfectly. I was trying to create an alias for the repeated column in the SELECT statement when I should have been trying to create an alias for the repeated table in the JOIN statement.

For anyone else who runs into this:

```
SELECT  
[TABLE1 NAME].[TABLE1 COLUMN],  
(TABLE2 ALIAS1).[TABLE2 COLUMN],  
(TABLE2 ALIAS2).[TABLE2 COLUMN],  
FROM [TABLE1 NAME]  
JOIN [TABLE2 NAME] (TABLE2 ALIAS1) ON [TABLE1 NAME].[TABLE1 MATCHING COLUMN] = (TABLE2 ALIAS1).[TABLE2 MATCHING COLUMN]  
JOIN [TABLE2 NAME] (TABLE2 ALIAS2) ON [TABLE1 NAME].[TABLE1 MATCHING COLUMN] = (TABLE2 ALIAS2).[TABLE2 MATCHING COLUMN]
```

The alias name is created in the JOIN statement and applied to where it is used in the SELECT statement, not the other way around.

Comment: Do you really believe that people can understand this? You made it more complicated that your original query. How about writing down the corrected SQL statement rather than confuse people with syntax that is not valid SQL